# Zip sparse sequences

Tags: scala

I have two sequences of objects, where the objects share a common attribute (lets call it id)

```
case class ThingA(id: Int, someAttribute: String)
case class ThingB(id: Int, someOtherAttribute: Float)
```

I want to join "sparse" lists, which is to say that every `ThingA.id` might not match a `ThingB.id` and vice versa.  The ids are unique in each list.

Example input:

```
val thingAs = Seq(ThingA(0, "foo"), ThingA(1, "bar"))
val thingBs = Seq(ThingB(0, 1.0), ThingB(2, 0.3))
```

Desired output:

```
val zipped: Seq(Tuple[Option[ThingA], Option[ThingB]]) = Seq(
    (Some(ThingA(0, "foo")), Some(ThingB(0, 1.0))),   // Matching id = 0
    (Some(ThingA(1, "bar")), None),
    (None, Some(ThingB(2, 0.3))
)
```

---

My current attempt looks like this:

```
val zipped = (
    thingAs.map(a => (Some(a), thingBs.find(b => b.id == a.id))) ++
    thingBs.map(b => (thingAs.find(a => a.id == b.id), Some(b)))
).distinct
```

which works, but I am hoping that there is a better way.

Comment: Look into `.groupBy`. Group one seq by by id, then `map` the other one to join.

Comment: @Dima, no point in the `.groupBy`? " The ids are unique in each list."

Comment: @ArchetypalPaul the point is lookups in a `Map` are constant time

Comment: Right, but there's no need for groupBy to turn it into a Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to compute first the union of all ids and then fetch the corresponding `ThingA` or `ThingB` instances using lookup maps, as @Dima suggested.

```
val lookupThingA = thingAs.map(x => x.id -> x).toMap
val lookupThingB = thingBs.map(x => x.id -> x).toMap

val zipped: Seq[(Option[ThingA], Option[ThingB])] =
    (lookupThingA.keySet | lookupThingB.keySet).map(i => (lookupThingA.get(i), lookupThingB.get(i))).toList
```

Output (note that you can have a `Set` instead of a `Seq`):

```
(Some(ThingA(1,bar)),None)
(Some(ThingA(0,foo)),Some(ThingB(0,1.0)))
(None,Some(ThingB(2,0.3)))
```

(I let it as a community wiki if anyone wants to improve this)

Comment: Actually `groupBy` is not the best fit here. `.map(x => x.id -> x).toMap` is better, as you don't wrap values in collections.